# Unable to access topic from scaled Kafka cluster in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerhub

I want to create scalable Kafka cluster on dockers. I am using docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/ for creating kafka server. For creating single node kafka and zookeeper I have used following docker-compose :

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  kafka:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka"
    ports:
     - "9095:9092"
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
     - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=check:3:1
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2185:2181"
```

with these settings I am able to access kafka broker and zookeeper from my application code as `kafka:9092` and `zookeeper:2181` respectively in kafka consumer settings.

But now I want scalable cluster so I have modified docker-compose as:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  kafka:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka"
    ports:
     - "9095:9092"
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
     - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=check:3:1
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2185:2181"
```

In this case 3 kafka brokers are getting created. But, in this case if I am unable to access my topic "check" by using kafka broker as `kafka:9092` and kafka zookeeper as `zookeepr:2181` in my application code's kafka consumer settings. How should I modify my `docker-compose.yml` OR my application code kafka consumer settings such that I can read from these multiple brokers?

Comment: is your application running within docker?

Comment: Having three containers on one machine won't make anything faster or truly fault tolerant via replication. In any case, Confluent documentation has examples of Docker Kafka clusters

Comment: @Saket yes, it is within docker